# SwipeRefreshLayout minimum Android API Version for usage

Tags: java, android, android-library

i wonder
can i use

"android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout"

between android 4.1(api level 16) & 5.1(22) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Wherever you see `android.support.v4` as part of the package, that class works back to API Level 4.